# How to auto-advance due to inactivity on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics, user-inactivity

I would like to auto-advance my participants in a Qualtrics survey to the next question (on the next page) after they have been inactive for 10 seconds. My inactivity code is working fine (see below, from [Kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/detecting_if_the_user_is_idle_or_inactive.htm)) but I can't figure out how to force the survey to move on. Any ideas?

Code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

    var timeoutID;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}

setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 10 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 10000);
}   


    function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    goActive();
}
 function goInactive() {
    // Here is where the auto-advance code needs to go

}

    function goActive() {

    startTimer();
}


});
```

--
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the goInactive function:

```
$('NextButton').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the official documentation [LINK HERE](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/survey-javascript-methods/)

```
this.clickNextButton();
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of the answer I gave.  The Qualtrics clickNextButton function has one line, which matches the answer I gave.

Comment: Ahh fair enough! Please confirm. The other answer. I have definitely used both before!